# can cygwin run things at startup

Tags: cygwin, startup

In normal Linux I can put things in rc.local to run at startup. Is there a way to do this in Cygwin? It seems that when I start the Cygwin terminal it doesn't automatically run anything.

Specifically, I wanted it to start mysqld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc